# Product of rank one updates as a low rank update for quasi newton/BFGS

Tags: linear-algebra, newton-method, quasi-newton

I'm trying to improve the speed of the following iteration to calculate $s_k$:

$$B_k^{-1} = \Bigg( I + \frac{s_{k}s_{k-1}^T}{||s_{k-1}||^2}\Bigg)...\Bigg(I+ \frac{s_1s_0^T}{||s_0||^2}\Bigg) B_0^{-1}\\s_{k+1} = -\frac{B_k^{-1}r_{k+1}}{1+\frac{s_k^TB_k^{-1}r_{k+1}}{||s_k||^2}}$$

If we calculate $B_k^{-1}$ explicitly then each step is roughly $O(n^4)$ to calculate $B_k^{-1}$. If instead we compute $B_k^{-1}r_{k+1}$ by expanding the product from the right, we do $k$ matrix-vector multiplications which is $O(n^3)$, a lot better.

Is there a way to find $s_k$ in the form of a low rank update using the value of previous $s_i$?

Comment: What do you mean by "find $s_k$ in the form of a low rank update"? $s_k$ is a vector, it has rank 1 (if rank is defined at all for vectors).

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, the recursion in BFGS is not the equation that you write, but a two-sided version of it (update matrices I + something on both sides of $B^{-1}$). Are you sure that this is the recursion that you wish to use? Do you realize that this version produces a non-symmetric $B_k^{-1}$, unlike the standard one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Sherman-Morrison Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) and some other tricks, detailed starting on page 124 of [Kelley, Iterative Methods for Linear and Nonlinear Equations](https://archive.siam.org/books/textbooks/fr16_book.pdf)